# TypeScript react-select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

i am stuck in a weird situation , I am learning typescript for the moment and this is so far what happened . i will post very minimal data :

```
 const [selectedBankCode , setSelectedBankCode] = useState<string | undefined>();
 const [selectedBank, setSelectedBank] = useState('');
 const [bankBranchOptions, setBankBranchOptions] = useState<{ name: string , code : string}[]>([]);
 const [bankBranchOptions, setBankBranchOptions] = useState<{ name: string , code : string}[]>([]);
 const [isLoadingBankBranches, setIsLoadingBankBranches] = useState(false);
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

 const initialValues = {

    bankName: '',
    bankBranch: ''

  }

  const registrationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    bankName: Yup.string()
      .min(1, 'Minimum 1 symbol')
      .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
      .test('bankSelected', intl.formatMessage({ id: 'INVALID_BANKNAME' }), (value) => {
        if ((value && bankOptions.length === 0) || value !== bankOptions[0]?.name) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
      .required(intl.formatMessage({id: 'BANK_NAME_ERROR'})),
    bankBranch: Yup.string()
      .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
      .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
      .test('bankBranchSelected', intl.formatMessage({ id: 'INVALID_BANKBRANCH' }), (value) => {
        console.log('bankBranch value : ',value)
        if (!value || value.trim() === '') {
          return false; // No bank branch selected
        }
        if (bankBranchOptions.length === 0) {
          return false; // Options not available
        }
        return true;
      })
      .required(intl.formatMessage({id: 'BANK_BRANCH_ERROR'}))
})

const getBankName = async (bankName :any) => {
    if (bankName !== '') {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://apis.bankcode-jp.com/v2/banks/?filter=name==${bankName}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_BANKCODESJP_KEYS}&limit=10`
        );
        if (response.data.size === 0) {
          formik.setFieldError('bankName', intl.formatMessage({ id: 'INVALID_BANKNAME' }));
          setBankOptions([{ name: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'NO_BANKNAME' }), code: '' }]);
        } else {
          const bankList = response?.data?.data;
          formik.setFieldError('bankName', '');
          setBankOptions(bankList.map((bank :any) => ({ name: bank.name, code: bank.code })));
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error while fetching bank name:', err);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const debouncedBankName = useDebounce(formik.values.bankName, 2000);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBankName(debouncedBankName);
  }, [debouncedBankName]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      getBankBranch();
    },2000)
  }, [selectedBankCode]);

  const getBankBranch = async () => {
    if (selectedBankCode) {
      setIsLoadingBankBranches(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://apis.bankcode-jp.com/v2/banks/${selectedBankCode}/branches?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_BANKCODESJP_KEYS}&limit=1000`
        );
        if (response.data.size === 0) {
          formik.setFieldError('bankBranch', intl.formatMessage({ id: 'INVALID_BANKBRANCH' }));
          setBankBranchOptions([{ name: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'NO_BANKBRANCH' }), code: '' }]);
        } else {
          const bankBranchList = response?.data?.data;
          console.log('bank branch list : ',bankBranchList)

          formik.setFieldError('bankBranch', '');
          // setBankBranchOptions(bankBranchList.map((bankBranch: any) => ({ name: bankBranch.name, code: bankBranch.code })));
          setBankBranchOptions(
            bankBranchList.map((bankBranch: any) => ({
              value: bankBranch.code,
              label: bankBranch.name,
            }))
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error while fetching bank branches:', err);
      }
      setIsLoadingBankBranches(false);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedBank) {
      const selectedBankObj = bankOptions.find((bank) => bank.name === selectedBank);
      if (selectedBankObj) {
        setSelectedBankCode(selectedBankObj.code);
      }
    } else {
      setSelectedBankCode(undefined);
      console.log('No bank selected.');
    }
  }, [selectedBank, bankOptions]);

 <Select
                     options={bankBranchOptions}
                     value={selectedBankBranch}
                     onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                     console.log(selectedOption)
                      formik.setFieldValue('bankBranch', selectedOption ? selectedOption.name : '');
                      console.log('formik.values after:', formik.values);
                      }}
                     className={clsx(
                       'form-control-solid',
                       {
                         'is-invalid': formik.touched.bankBranch && formik.errors.bankBranch,
                       },
                       {
                         'is-valid': formik.touched.bankBranch && !formik.errors.bankBranch,
                       }
                     )}
                     placeholder={
                       bankBranchOptions.length === 0
                         ? 'No Bank Branches available'
                         : intl.formatMessage({ id: 'SELECT.BANK_BRANCH' })
                     }
                  />
```

Now my problem here is :
console.log(selectedOption) // it displays as {value : 'xyz',label : 'abcd'} (because we map them as value and label )

but when i do this :

```
 formik.setFieldValue('bankBranch', selectedOption ? selectedOption.name : '');
```

it stores bankBranch as undefined , because theres no selectedOption.name !! , but if i change code to

```
 formik.setFieldValue('bankBranch', selectedOption ? selectedOption.label : '');
```

i get this error as  : Property 'label' does not exist on type '{ name: string; code: string; }'

which means selectedOption uses `{name : string , code : string}` when i hover over selectedOption inside onChange

Can anyone help me out from this weird puzzle please , stuck since long time

thank you _/_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NB: The react-select value needs to be in the same format as the options.**

First you need to change the type of `bankBranchOptions` to use label and value since react-select uses that format.

```
const [bankBranchOptions, setBankBranchOptions] = useState<
  { label: string; value: string }[]
>([]);
```

based on the above options, our formik init values needs to be the same

```
const initialValues: InitValues = {
  bankName: "",
  bankBranch: [{label: '', value: ''}]
}
```

react-select onChange returns an object with label and value properties. doing this won't work

```
formik.setFieldValue('bankBranch', selectedOption ? selectedOption.name : '');
```

to set the value of react-select, use the value from formik

```
value={selectedBankBranch}
```

to

```
value={formik.values.bankBranch}
```

Here's an example

```
<Select
    options={bankBranchOptions}
    value={formik.values.bankBranch} 
    onChange={(selectedOption) => {
      formik.setFieldValue("bankBranch", selectedOption?.label);
    }}
  />
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/empty-hill-33sypg)

Comment: made the required changes , i get some error in options here , when i hover over it , it says : 
Array of options that populate the select menu

Type '{ label: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly (string | GroupBase<string>)[]'.
  Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | GroupBase<string>'.
    Property 'options' is missing in type '{ label: string; value: string; }' but required in type 'GroupBase<string>'.ts(2322)

Comment: even you get the same issue in the codesandbox which you provided @junius L

Comment: I've updated it